# What is the default recommended compiler for mex compiling C++ source files that require Intel MKL as linear algebra package?

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-c++, mingw-w64, intel-mkl

Is it Intel’s proprietary C/C++ compiler, or does it also work with Microsoft Visual C++?

After many days of experimenting, I have got stuck with dependencies, so I have come to the decision to ask this question here.

I highly appreciate any answer from more experienced members of StackOverflow. Thank you in advance.

I presume that the MinGW64 compiler is not supported in this case.

In my opinion, the question in the header must be the most common use case on Windows.

My setup: Windows 10, MATLAB R2091b, Intel MKL.